# UNIX - Find command clarification

Tags: find

I want to find an list of files which doesn't have 777 and 775 permission and also specific user.

I used `find` command as below.

```
find /usr/bin/ -type f ! \( -perm 775 -o -perm 777 -o -user abc \) -exec ls -ltr {} \;  2>>/dev/null
```

But it's returning wrong values.

Comment: What wrong values are returned? What OS are you running?

Comment: Your one-liner will list files that have different permissions than 775 OR 777 OR ownership differs from user abc. You should use `-a` instead of `-o`

Comment: You can also combine `find` with `grep`: `find /usr/bin/ -type f -exec ls -al {} \; |grep -Ev 'rwxrwxrwx.*abc\|rwxrwxr-x.*abc'`, but this one would list a file with 775 or 777 permissions if owner = `abc` or if file's name matches user `abc`

Comment: @alex Using `-a` wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: @alex because permissions can't be both 0755 *and* 0777 at the same time.

Comment: Indeed. Find should be split into `\(-perm 775 -o -user abc\) -o \(-perm 777 -o -user abc\)` but I am not sure if `find` supports this.